# Изменение вида продуктов через javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-программирование, django

Задача заключается в следующем.
Нужно сделать кнопку, которая переключает вид товаров на сайте(кубиками или списком).
Из моих идей:

- Через ajax посылать запрос, а в ответ получать страницу с товарами в требуемом стиле
- Через js редактировать html код товаров(какой-то костыль, кажется)
- Другая страница в требуемом формате(самый худший вариант, как понимаете)

---

Прошу помочь с этой задачей. Как ее лучше решить? Может есть более простой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае стоит просто манипулировать стилями:

```js
var products = document.getElementById('products');

document.getElementById('grid').addEventListener('click', function(){
  products.classList.add('grid');
});

document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function(){
  products.classList.remove('grid');
});
```

```css
.product {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.grid .product {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button id="list">Список</button>
<button id="grid">Сетка</button>

<div id="products">
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут внутри блоков могут возникнуть проблемы с вёрсткой в случае (а он наверняка будет) разного размера описания товаров, например :) И как быть, если например нужно картинки размещать попеременно с правой и левой стороны? Решение весьма ограничено :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это уже совсем другой вопрос ;) Или flex или фикс высота, или еще что-то

Comment: Я делал динамическую генерацию  размеров и позиции в html по нажатию кнопки. В принципе на стороне сервера выглядит не намного сложнее javascript, местами даже проще. Под эту задачу тот код не подойдёт, потому не предлагаю :)

Answer (score 1):

А в чем, собственно, заключается костыльность второго варианта?

Ставите две кнопки, которые будут переключать стили у блоков товара. И делаете количество выдаваемых единиц кратное количеству столбцов при изменении на "сетку". Насколько я знаю, таким способом пользуются все популярные торговые площадки.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Больше похоже на комментарий... с уточняющим вопросом к  автору.